# Extract count of single category from a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count, extract

I currently have a DataFrame containing info on e-mails sent from one job title to another.

```
      fromJobtitle         toJobtitle  e-mails
0              CEO                CEO       65
1              CEO           Director       23
2              CEO           Employee       56
3              CEO    In House Lawyer        7
4              CEO            Manager      104
..             ...                ...      ...
87  Vice President  Managing Director      112
88  Vice President          President      385
89  Vice President             Trader       78
90  Vice President            Unknown     1088
91  Vice President     Vice President     2304
```

And I am looking for a way so that it is possible to get a total count for each job title.
The example output would be:

```
        totalJobtitle       e-mails
0                 CEO           670
1   Managing Director          2341
2      Vice President          4720
3            Employee          3560
4              Trader           250
```

Comment: Do you need to count emails twice if either sender or receiver is `CEO` for example? What if both sender and receiver are same?

Comment: Check the [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [agg](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) methods to get something like: df.groupby(['fromJobtitle']).agg({'e-mails':'sum'})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a small example of what I could work with

```
d = {'fromJobtitle': ["CEO", "CEO","VicePresident","VicePresident"], 'mail': [3, 4, 5, 6 ]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

df:

```
    fromJobtitle    mail
0   CEO 3
1   CEO 4
2   VicePresident   5
3   VicePresident   6
```

now this:

```
 df = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['fromJobtitle'],values=['mail'],aggfunc=np.sum)
```

df:

```
fromJobtitle    mail    
CEO 7
VicePresident   11
```

the source of the function:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html